# Minify ES6 JS Code in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, bundling-and-minification, uglifyjs

In my Meteor site, I recently discovered that the Javascript was not minified in production. A quick look into the plugins revealed, that the *standard-minifiers-js* package was missing. Once I added this and tried it via *meteor --production*, I quickly discovered, that uglify-js (which is used in *standard-minifiers-js*) does not support ES6. As the whole project is written using ES6, this can't be changed. There is, however, a package called *uglify-es* which should be able to minify ES6, but I don't know how to get Meteor's standard minifiers to use it (a solution without manually replacing packages, which might be overwritten and has to be done on each server the project is installed would be best)

TL;DR:
How can I get *standard-minifiers-js* from Meteor to use *uglify-es* instead of *uglify-js* ?

Comment: Don't you use `babel` to transpile ES6?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ecmascript` package as well as `standard-minifiers-js`.

`ecmascript` will transpile your ES6 with babel before minification